# Using CRLF to bypass xss

Tags: javascript, xss

Recently I have seen some people posting about their xss polygots,

I encounter a problem where everyone was talking about using crlf to bypass XSS .

I dont understand how can CRLF be used to bypass XSS filters.

Please do let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The way your question is written suggests you haven't researched this at all.

Comment: @Amy I have but i'm still confused . I understand that that some places where we can't use characters like  | ` it will be legit. But i dont get why to use it in place of > and <

Comment: Nevermind got the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an example in order to better explain this.
But the general idea is that CRLF characters are interpreted by server-side languages (such as PHP for example), but are discarded as whitespace by HTML, which will allow you to potentially bypass server-side filters (as it's not what they are blocking) and be thrown into the DOM, where it is then more or less stripped of the CRLF character and executes the payload.

Example:

```
<iframe src="{$user_input}"></iframe>
```

Lets imagine that we take user input where the variable `{$user_input}` can be found. You may be aware that input injected into an iframe source is dangerous, as an attacker can input `javascript:alert(0)` as their input and receive an alert. Feel free to try that out and you'll see.

So, lets imagine a developer hears that someone has been using this vulnerability to get XSS on their website. They decide to create a rule in which they strip `javascript:` from the input before inputting to source. There are now 3 potential ways to get XSS.

The first is to do something like `jAvAsCrIpT:alert(0)`. This will work if the method of replacing is case sensitive.

The second method is to try something like so: `javajavascript:script:alert(0)`. This will also work as it will simply strip `javascript:` leaving it as `javascript:alert(0)`.

The third and final way (that I can think of at least, there is probably more methods) would be to use a CRLF/Line Feed character. You can do this: `java%0a%0dscript:alert(0)` which is a URL encoded CRLF character (`%0a%0d`). This will bypass it as PHP reads that as not being actually `javascript:` whilst the HTML will read it as whitespace within an attribute value (`src`) and ignore the carriage return.